# Does Java 11 or 12 supports Struts 1.3?

Tags: java, struts, upgrade, struts-1, java-11

Am trying to upgrade maven Struts 1.3 built using Java 1.7 to Java 1.8 and was able to successfully launch the application after changing all possible library files. Now, it has been instructed to upgrade the application to Java 11 or 12. Does Java 11 or 12 supports Struts 1.3 ? Can I proceed to make this changes? Your thoughts please.

Comment: Struts 1.3.10 was last released December 2008, 10.5 years ago. It's time to upgrade. Anyhow the question isn't whether java supports struts but whether struts supports a particular version of java. Did you try to run it on java 11? What happened?

Comment: FWIW, according to the announcement page, Struts support for Java 11 was added in the Struts 2.5.20 GA release.  So the answer to your question is "probably no".

Comment: Given Java's general backward compatibility it should work... that said there can be subtle difference that will cause it to fail though I can think of any between 1.8 and 11.

Comment: It might work, but if you look at the list of known security vulnerabilities (https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-45/product_id-6117/version_id-121558/Apache-Struts-1.3.10.html) I would recommend to migrate to a newer struts version.

Comment: Given that [support for Struts 2.3 has ended](https://struts.apache.org/struts23-eol-announcement), Struts 1.3 is surely no longer supported or maintained iwth security patches. I realize that the decision to continue using Struts 1.3 is probably not yours, but as @ThomasKläger pointed out, your Struts 1.3 applications will be highly vulnerable. (I realize that this does not address your actual question at all, but you may want to raise this matter with whoever is making the decisions.)