# Does Struts1.x compatible with Java11/Java12?

Tags: struts, struts-1, java-11, struts-config, java-12

Am working in a project where the application runs in Struts 1.3 and Java 7, We now need to upgrade the Java version to the latest [just java alone and not Struts]

When upgraded to Java 8, we managed to run the application with Struts 1.3 however I now need to update the Java to 11 or 12 version.

Can any of you please confirm the latest version of Java that will support Struts 1.3?

Is there any official announcement made in Struts community?

Comment: Struts 1 is EOL since 2013; Java 12 was released in 2019 - what do you expect? if isn't working out of the box then you are out of luck ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56521038/does-java-11-or-12-supports-struts-1-3

Comment: Test it. And don't create new users for identical questions. There will never be any "official announcements" regarding Struts 1.3 other than "It's EOL, there is no official support for anything".

Comment: @Adrian, Java 8 was released in 2014 but it supports Struts 1 which is EOL since 2013. I may or may not support Java 11 but thought of getting the opinions before we spend some time on the activity.

Comment: @Dave, Yes, am testing it by doing a POC now, but facing numerous challenges. I just need to get some second opinions from others if they have performed similar POC earlier. Thanks.

Comment: We are in the same boat. Its hard to justify the rewrite when everything still works fine (the security vulnerabilities are actually avoided in our system). Did you get any further in your research?